# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement

Tags: jaxb

I'm trying to migrate my project from java8 to the new java21.
I'm using Hibernate 6.44, and I'm facing issues with the jaxb classes.

I've already tried to adjust my pom.xml file with those parts:

```
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.xml.bind/jakarta.xml.bind-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
```

but still having issues.

Every time i run the code I get:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:137)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.<init>(JaxbAnnotationIntrospector.java:124)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.module.jaxb.JaxbAnnotationModule.setupModule(JaxbAnnotationModule.java:98)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModule(ObjectMapper.java:906)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.registerModules(ObjectMapper.java:1108)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.findAndRegisterModules(ObjectMapper.java:1192)
    at org.hibernate.type.format.jackson.JacksonJsonFormatMapper.<init>(JacksonJsonFormatMapper.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.type.format.jackson.JacksonIntegration.<clinit>(JacksonIntegration.java:18)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.lambda$determineJsonFormatMapper$6(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:803)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:220)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.selector.internal.StrategySelectorImpl.resolveDefaultableStrategy(StrategySelectorImpl.java:180)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.determineJsonFormatMapper(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:799)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.<init>(SessionFactoryOptionsBuilder.java:305)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.DefaultSessionFactoryBuilderService.createSessionFactoryBuilder(DefaultSessionFactoryBuilderService.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.getSessionFactoryBuilder(MetadataImpl.java:170)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1503)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:55)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
    at com.cryptoprojects.arbicrypto.components.commons.database.Database.<init>(Database.java:73)
    at com.cryptoprojects.arbicrypto.components.commons.database.Database.initialize(Database.java:98)
    at com.cryptoprojects.arbicrypto.Main.main(Main.java:63)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
    ... 22 more
```

Searched a lot but not found any solution.

I appreciate if anyone could help me to get it work.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved adding:

```
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```